# Analyzing multiple Json with Tableau

Tags: json, tableau-api

I'm beginning to use Tableau and I have a project involving multiple website logs stored as JSON. I have one log for each day for about a month, each weighting about 500-600 Mb.

Is it possible to open (and join) multiple JSON files in Tableau? If yes, how ? I can load them in parallel, but not join them.
EDIT : I can load multiple JSON files and define their relationship, so this is OK. I still have the memory issue:

I'm am worried that by joining them all, I will not have enough memory to make it work. Are the loaded files stored in RAM of in an internal DB ?

What would be the best way to do this ? Should I merge all the JSON first, or load them in a database and use a connector to Tableau? If so, what could be a good choice of DB?

I'm aware some of these questions are opinion-based, but I have no clue about this and I really need some guideline to get started.

Comment: Do you want to join them or union them? I believe the UNION feature with Tableau's JSON driver is not (yet) available. For this volume of data, you probably want to preprocess, filter, aggregate and index it ahead of time - either using a database, something like Parquet and Spark and/or Tableau extracts

Comment: I have the same data every day, so I need a union. When working with a database, how does tableau uses memory? Does it load everything at the beginning, or retrieve and aggregate when needed?

Comment: Tableau sends a query to the database and then renders a visualization based on the query result set. The volume of data returned depends on the query which depends on what you specify in Tableau. Tableau caches results, and you can also create an extract which serves as a persistent, potentially filtered and aggregated, cache. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31171086/441979

Comment: That is the case if I use a connection to a database, but what happens if I load a local text file (JSON or csv)? Does tableau store it in a DB, or load evrything in memory?

Comment: For text files and extracts, Tableau loads them into memory via its Data Engine process today -- replaced by a new in-memory database in the future. The concept is the same though, Tableau sends the data source a query which returns a result set. For data of the size you are talking about, you might want to test using some sort of database if it the volume exceeds what comfortably fits in memory

Comment: Thanks, can you put all that in an answer so I can give you some credit for your time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this volume of data, you probably want to preprocess, filter, aggregate and index it ahead of time - either using a database, something like Parquet and Spark and/or Tableau extracts.

If you use extracts, you probably want to filter and aggregate them for specific purposes, just be aware if that that you aggregate the data when you make the extract, you need to be careful that any further aggregations you perform in the visualization are well defined. Additive functions like SUM(), MIN() and MAX() are safe. Sums of partial sums are still correct sums. But averages of averages and count distincts of count distincts often are not.

Tableau sends a query to the database and then renders a visualization based on the query result set. The volume of data returned depends on the query which depends on what you specify in Tableau. Tableau caches results, and you can also create an extract which serves as a persistent, potentially filtered and aggregated, cache. See [this related stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31171086/441979)

For text files and extracts, Tableau loads them into memory via its Data Engine process today -- replaced by a new in-memory database called Hyper in the future. The concept is the same though, Tableau sends the data source a query which returns a result set. For data of the size you are talking about, you might want to test using some sort of database if it the volume exceeds what comfortably fits in memory.

The JSON driver is very convenient for exploring JSON data, and I would definitely start there. You can avoid an entire ETL step if that serves your needs. But at high volume of data, you might need to move to some sort of external data source to handle production loads. FYI, the UNION feature with Tableau's JSON driver is not (yet) available as of version 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer which nobody gave is that No, you cannot join two JSON files in Tableau. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can join 2 `JSON` tables in `Tableau`.

First extract the column names from the `JSON` data as below--

```
select
   get_json_object(JSON_column, '$.Attribute1') as Attribute1,
   get_json_object(line, '$.Attribute2') as Attribute2
   from table_name;
```

perform the above for the required tableau and join them.